# Is a Firestore database suitable for this time-series data or should I implement something else?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a flutter app with a Firestore backend.

I want to save timeseries data from sensor readings and I would like to use the firestore database if possible since I use it for everything else. Data is generated once per minute and there are 12 values and an index (count_seconds). Later I want to show bar charts of the data on the flutter app on any phone logged into the same account.

There will be thousands of phones uploading data.

I'm writing data like so:

> ```
>   DocumentReference history = Firestore.instance.collection("devices").document(deviceId).collection('updates').document("history");
>   history.setData({
>     "values": FieldValue.arrayUnion(
>       [
>         {
>           countSeconds.toString(): [
>             value0,
>             value1,
>             value2,
>             value3,
>             value4,
>             value5,
>             value6,
>             value7,
>             value8,
>             value9,
>             value10,
>             value11
>           ]
>         }
>       ],
>     )
>   }, merge: true);
> ```

Its stored as arrays in an array per device.

When I navigate to the firestore database page for the database it takes a long time to show the page.

[image: firestore database]

I'm concerned that this is the wrong approach. I understand that when I retrieve the data I will select only the data needed for the view. The last 200 rows for example. I'm not sure if this will be slow. I know there is a 1MB limit per document but I'm not sure how many rows this equates to.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding "lots" of data to Firestore, it's generally not a good idea to add those items to an array in a single document.  You're supposed to create a new document for each item.  Yes, that's a lot of document reads, but you won't run into any [size or rate limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions).